# PHP Check if values have changed with multiple variables

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a form which uses PHP and Mysql, I wanted help knowing how can I check if the values sent have changed from the ones that were before.
This form is used to update the information on the database, the page has multiple inputs, in which I show the old data so they can update it.

I would like to check if the posted data is not the same as the old data in the database so no query to update is done.
If the name and the email are the same as the previous data then don't update the data

```
if (($_POST['name'] == $name) AND ($_POST['email'] == $email)) {
echo "They are the same";
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: What is `$name`? What is `$bio`?

Comment: So if I am guessing correctly you want to know if the values being sent to the database from the form are the same or not? If so you can do this using your query.

Comment: The fundamental issue behind this question involves knowing what the previous values were. You need to edit your question to give some insight into how you are storing the previous values, and how you are trying to retrieve them in order for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're saving to a database (which I assume you are), the database engine automatically checks whether the values to be saved are equal to the already existing ones. If they haven't changed, then no query will be run. Thus, let your DB take care of this concern.